# Autoplay videos in iPhones with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, video, html5-video

I am building a game based on html5 video elements and scenario is like when a video ends the other video starts by detecting the on `ended`event like this.

```
video.on("ended", function() {
   someothervideo.play();
    });
```

This is working fine on all browsers and android phones but not working on iPhones. 
After doing a hours of research I came to know about [iOS's new video policies](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/) and it makes sense

But there's a note in this above mentioned link i.e

> A note about the user gesture requirement: when we say that an action must have happened “as a result of a user gesture”, we mean that the JavaScript which resulted in the call to `video.play()`, for example, must have directly resulted from a handler for a `touchend`, `click`, `doubleclick`, or `keydown` event. So, `button.addEventListener('click', () => { video.play(); })` would satisfy the user gesture requirement. `video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', () => { video.play(); })` would not.

According to the line

> `button.addEventListener('click', () => { video.play(); })` would satisfy the user gesture requirement.

I tried to put a button in the DOM like its not displayed anywhere

```
<button id="fakedbtn" style="left:-999999999px">Faked button</button>
```

And changed my above event listener to

```
video.on("ended", function() {
       $('#fakedbtn').on('click',function(){
        someothervideo.play();
       });
  $('#fakedbtn').trigger('click');
});
```

But for some reason, this **isn't working** either. Can someone explain this behavior? And suggest me some other thing to do the trick? The video can't be muted otherwise it would've worked.
**Note:** I've also tried to convert the above logic in javascript by using `addEventListener` and stuff but still no luck.

Comment: What you are doing could still be considered a violation of their policy (starting a video without user intervention). I wouldn't be surprised if Apple anticipated on your little trick and blocked the loophole.

Comment: @RuudHelderman yeah maybe, but do you know any other workaround?

Comment: You said you are building a game. That suggests there is regular input from the player. Try to piggyback your 'play' event on any one of those input events (user gestures). If there is really no such event (i.e. the player is supposed to wait for the video to end and not touch the screen), then it makes more sense to stitch the two videos together to one long video. That way you do not need a 'play' event halfway through.

Comment: I used the promise the media element returns and checked if the video can be autoplayed or not. If not I showed a button saying "Next" to solve the problem :) anyways thanks for your time